# WPF DataGrid Remove SelectedItems

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selecteditem

Recently I've been working on a project which imports data programmicaly into a WPF DataGrid.

I'm almost done with the project but the thing that I left out was a button to remove selected cells and this is where I'm stuck!

I wrote this code using my basic knowledge of DataGrids:

```
var grid = dataGrid1;
if (grid.SelectedIndex >= 0)
 {
   for (int i = 0; i <= grid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
   {
      grid.Items.Remove(grid.SelectedItems[i]);
   };
 }
```

Works fine on removing only the item selected just like CurrentItem but it doesn't remove anymore than 2 selected items!

The DataGrid I have should at least contain a minimum of 100 items. I've added a remove all option but this is also necessary.

I'll be thankful if anyone gives me the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By removing selected item you are changing `SelectedItems` collection. You should copy it first and then start removing.

Answer (score 4):

This also worked well for me.

```
while (dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count > 0){
  dataGrid1_item_source.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGrid1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you are doing here you are removing items during loop whaich is messing with loop count so make a copy grid and remove selecteditem from it and then equlize it by the orignal one..
 Check this out

```
var grid = dataGrid1;
var mygrid = dataGrid1
if (grid.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= grid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
  {
    mygrid .Items.Remove(grid.SelectedItems[i]);  
   };
}

grid = mygrid;
```

Comment: Tnx! I copied SelectedItem object into a new object and added to the loop.

Comment: This does nothing because `grid` and `mygrid` are the same `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
while (dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count > 0){
  dataGrid1_item_source.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGrid1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: If you sorted the DataGrid, his does not work because the indices are different than the underlying item source. Also, it would be dataGrid1_item_source.RemoveAt(dataGrid1.SelectedIndex); Rows is not in an ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
if (DataGrid1.SelectedItem != null) 
{
  DataRowView(DataGrid1.SelectedItem).Row.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A while loop using the **SelectedItem** instead of the **SelectedIndex**

```
while (dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count > 0){
  if (dataGrid1.SelectedItem == CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder)
      dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Remove(grid.SelectedItem);
  else
      dataGrid1.Items.Remove(dataGrid1.SelectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have stack with the same problem as an author. And found quite beautiful (I think) solution.

And so the main problem is that the [SelectedItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selecteditem%28VS.95%29.aspx) dynamic, and when you delete one row, it is recalculated again.

And so my code looks like this:

```
for (int i = -datagrid1.SelectedItems.Count; i < datagrid1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            datagrid1.SelectedItems.RemoveAt(datagrid1.SelectedIndex);
        }
```

So, every time the for loop is doing step 1, datagrid1.SelectedItems.Count is decreased by 1, and the variable i increases.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While dgData.SelectedItems.Count > 0
 dgData.SelectedItem.Row.Delete()
Loop
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (if you are using adonet with autogeneratecolumns=true);

```
for (int i = dgv.SelectedItems.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
     DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)dgv.SelectedItems[i];
     dataRow.Delete();
}
```