# Delete Selected row from datagrid wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I created a DataGrid. There are informations from database. i want delete selected row from datagrid and from database with button. i wrote these codes, program is running but when i click delete button there are Error "InvalidOperationException was unhandled". And what i must write my xaml file in datagrid tag ?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var selectedItem = dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            dataGrid1.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF DataGrid Remove SelectedItems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398046/wpf-datagrid-remove-selecteditems)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete by using row number.

```
dataGrid1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGrid1.SelectedIndex);
```

Hope that works.

Comment: what i must write datagrid tags in xaml?